# appengine app deployment - ERROR: At least one handler must be provided

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Getting started with appengine.

My app has no front end.

Its a tcp/udp socket server.

When I try to deploy I get the error in the title.

Handler for what? Its not a webapp.

Is appengine the wrong google service for server apps?

Comment: Are you using standart, or flexible environment? See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sockets/#using_sockets_with_the_development_server

Comment: If you was using standart will not works! You need to deploy webapp like specification. Vide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/

Comment: @AristofanioGarcia thanks for the docs. Deploying a socket app is a completely different can of worms

Comment: if it's a real server it MUST handle the requests, can you reveal the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a skeleton web handler (which may simply return a 404) to keep the deployment utility happy.

But be aware that the GAE standard environment sandbox is very restrictive for socket-based apps, see [Limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions_if_lang_is_java_java_7_runtime_only_endif):

> Although App Engine supports sockets, there are certain limitations
>   and behaviors you need to be aware of when using sockets :
>
> - Sockets are available only for paid apps.
> - You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets.
> - FTP is not supported.
> - You can only use TCP or UDP; arbitrary protocols are not allowed.
> - You cannot bind to specific IP addresses or ports.
> - Port 25 (SMTP) is blocked; you can still use authenticated SMTP on the submission port 587.
> - Private, broadcast, multicast, and Google IP ranges (except those whitelisted below), are blocked:
>
>   - Google Public DNS: `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`, `2001:4860:4860::8888`, `2001:4860:4860::8844` port 53
>   - Gmail SMTPS: smtp.gmail.com port 465 and 587
>   - Gmail POP3S: pop.gmail.com port 995
>   - Gmail IMAPS: imap.gmail.com port 993
>
>     Note: Google Compute Engine IP addresses are not considered to be in Google IP ranges. You can use sockets to connect Google App Engine
>       apps to Google Compute Engine instances.
> - Socket descriptors are associated with the App Engine app that created them and are non-transferable (cannot be used by other apps).
> - Sockets may be reclaimed after 2 minutes of inactivity; any socket operation keeps the socket alive for a further 2 minutes.

If your app can't abide by these restrictions you need to look at other alternatives, which would include the flexible environment GAE or Compute Engine.